# 3d Graph Error with Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have a problem with plotting a 3d-graph

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
     title=Exmple using the mesh parameter,
     hide axis,
     colormap/cool,
  ]
  \addplot3[
     mesh,
     samples = 40,
     domain=0:1,
    ]
    {exp(-(ln(x)-ln(y))};
  \addlegendentry{$\frac{sin(r)}{r}$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is

> Package pdfplots Error: An internal error occurred during z buffer reordering: the rows/cols where not balanced! I have rows=40, cols=40. If this happens to be wrong, you might want to provide rows and cols manually...

Is there anyone who knows how to fix the problem? It works e.g. with the function sin(x)*sin(y)...

Answer (score 2):

ln(0) is not defined! Use

```
domain=0.01:1,
```